How to Generate Text with Specific Length Using AI API
I am attempting to generate text outputs that are exactly a certain number of characters or words long using AI API (OpenAI GPT, Claude, Gemini...), but I'm facing difficulties. Here's what I've tried so far:
Setting Max Tokens: I've used the max_tokens parameter hoping to limit the output length, but then text is truncated.
Explicit Prompt Requests: I've tried including explicit instructions in the prompt about the desired length. However, this approach has not produced the precise output lengths I need (ex: gives 600 words instead of 800).
I am looking for suggestions on how to configure the API calls or promtp to achieve exact output lengths. Is there a way to better utilize OpenAI/Claude’s parameters, or is there a method to post-process the text to fit the required length?
I need this because I inject the text in slides. Any alternative solution?

This won't work. LLMs are bad at counting. There are a lot of humorous examples over internet.

Thx for your answer. That's why I am looking for an alternative solution to meet my goal of being able to fill slides nicely

I think if the goal is to fill slides, it is better to do it manually or help yourself with some python code, that will check when there is text length overflow.
Autogenerating slides is... slippery slope anyway :)

haha yep I was expecting a magic alternative :p thanks tho
